# How to query MongoDB collection using mongoose discriminators

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discriminator

I am trying to read from a Mongo database using mongoose where the models make use of the discriminator inheritance functionality, but the documents in the DB are all inserted by another service (using the Java Mongo driver) which does not use mongoose nor its discriminators. All of my queries using subclass models (those which use the discriminator function) return empty arrays when I try to read from the DB. I think it's because mongoose is expecting those documents to contain a discriminator key, however the service which is inserting the documents has no knowledge of discriminator keys, and thus isn't setting them on the mongoDB documents.

How can I create my models and use the discriminator function such that they can still query for these documents inserted by another service?

For more context, I want to use discriminators because inheritance allows me to cleanly structure the fields of the models I'm creating and define model-specific static methods, and it lets me not write duplicate code. If there is a better way to accomplish these goals without using mongoose's built-in discriminator pattern, please share!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html):

> The way mongoose tells the difference between the different
>   discriminator models is by the 'discriminator key', which is __t by
>   default. Mongoose adds a String path called __t to your schemas that
>   it uses to track which discriminator this document is an instance of.

Also mongoose saves documents with discriminators to the single collections.

So, in order to have access to the documents you need to save __t parameter, and check if you save schemas with the same discriminators to a single collection